# ZeroMQ vs Oracle queuing

Tags: oracle, message-queue, zeromq, distributed-system

I'm junior backend developer and now I'm working on a project about bank, which is a distributed system. What I knew before was that there were some message library such as **`ZeroMQ`** to realize the communication between components in a distributed system. But now, in the project, they used oracle queuing.

My colleague told me that this was better because we had no risk to lose any message to send even if processes die accidently.

**My questions**:
**`Q1:`** If Oracle queuing is better, when should we use things like `ZeroMQ`?
and
**`Q2:`** What is the disadvantage of Oracle queuing, comparing with `ZeroMQ`?

Comment: The main point is probably that you use already Oracle as your database , so you can use it for queueing too. It's like a feature for free...

Comment: Oracle's AQ disadvantage is clear - performance (and also price). And sometimes also you may face some bugs. For the rest of features AQ beat other (free) messaging systems, transaction support, XA support, online backup support, HA clustering support, ...

Comment: ZeroMQ is **not a queueing mechanism**. It's a **transport** mechanism that comes with queueing in order to perform certain things, like peer discovery after binding etc. You can persist data queued by ZeroMQ, but it doesn't come out of the box. The other advantage of ZMQ is that there's nothing as fast at the market, plus other goodies if you're a developer that deals with distributed systems. ZMQ doesn't lose messages. Your friend made wrong assumptions about ZMQ and didn't do his homework. This is why we read the manuals before listening to random rambles of our peer developers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your colleague is right here, because Oracle AQ comes with persistence and zeroMQ is in-memory. You'd use zeroMQ if you need max messages per second (millions). Price isn't a thing, because Oracle doesn't charge extra for AQ, it's even free with Oracle XE.

If your application relies on Oracle already, there are no disadvantages putting the messaging into Oracle.

Comment: There are many examples how to make ZMQ messages persistent (Malamute broker, Titanic service protocol). That categorically dismisses the "friend" being correct and shifts the discussion around.

Comment: I failed to find any examples of how to implement persistent ZMQ. The fact that it *can* be done with ZMQ only highlights that ZMQ is not the right tool for the job as it only covers transport and *not* persistent queuing. OP stated clearly that they chose AQ for reliability.

Comment: I'm not commenting to highlight that ZMQ is the right tool. I'm debating the part where OP's friend said that ZMQ is unreliable - it's simply false. It's a transport layer using several communication protocols - one of them being TCP which was made for the purposes of reliable communication over unreliable wire. As for how to make ZMQ persistent - I won't question how you failed to find the examples, but here's the [whole plethora of examples, with explanation and code examples](http://zguide.zeromq.org/php:chapter4).

Comment: It *is* unreliable because it might loose messages in case the broker is shut down. The examples are really great and well done, but especially the titanic implementation is nothing I'd use in production.

Comment: Any process can lose messages before committing. Even databases do, that's why they warn you that you can lose up to 1 second worth of transactions. ZeroMQ guide shows you how to achieve the same functionality. Also, you don't have to use a broker for p2p connections. Your answer is misleading and based on no facts. OP's friend isn't entirely correct. While AQ probably is the right tool for the job, it's totally unwise to provide completely false facts about a different product. Sorry, but the colleague isn't entirely correct and this will provide potentially dangerous false info.

Comment: I don't know which database you're referring to, but in Oracle it's guaranteed that already written but uncommitted data is rolled back after a server crash whereas committed data will never be lost - not even a microsecond of data. Without persistence you have to choose between one of two evils: either you transmit synchronously (slow) or you have a broker in between and deal with a potential loss of data.